# In Eclipse, how to make Flat Presentation default in the Team Perspective?

Tags: eclipse, svn

When using a centralized versioning system like CVS or SVN, I like to review my changes in the *Team Synchronizing View* before I commit them.
By default Eclipse collapses the source tree, and I always have to click on the little arrow in the icon "Show Java Workspace" and select the checkbox for *Flat Presentation*:

[image: Dropdown menu for choosing flat presentation]

Is there a way to make this the default for the Synchronizing perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do that for SVN, unchecking the option *Allow models to participate in synchronizations*:

[image: Eclipse - Team - SVN - View Settings]

The same can be done for CVS in *Team* -> *CVS* -> *Synchronize/Compare* settings, though I haven't really tested it.

**UPDATE:** If that does not work on the first time, on the View Menu (activated clicking the little arrow beside the minimize button for the Synchronize panel), select *Presentation* -> *Tree*.

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences > Team > Choose the presentation to be used when displaying Workspace projects : Flat

Comment: It does not work here, does it work for you? Thanks for the attention, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"The same can be done for CVS in Team -> CVS -> Synchronize/Compare settings, though I haven't tested it."

Tested it for CVS. Doesn't work. Scumbag Eclipse :/